# In Task Manager "System" is using GPU for "GPU 1 - Copy"?

Tags: windows, gpu, optimus

I have a laptop (integrated intel and discrete Nvidia). Ideally, the discrete GPU should not be used since it uses twice as much power as anything else combined for light workloads. However, I can see that "System" process in task manager is waking up my Nvidia GPU once every few minutes to do a GPU 1 - Copy task that lasts a second. Any idea what might cause this?

Plugging and unplugging usb-a devices (GPU is directly connected to the USB-C/thunderbolt, but USB-a ports shouldn't have this behavior) also wake the GPU for a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

People downgrading to Nvidia 466.77 version of drivers resolved it. Reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/ly5hk5/system_gpu_1_copy_keeping_laptop_nvidia_gpu_awake/

Myself I have a Quadro card and upgraded on top of my ThinkPad drivers (which bundled some Nvidia drivers) to the production branch of 472.47.

Again my battery life, temperatures, fan noise restored back as I was expecting it.